# Is this a property of the expected value and variance?

Tags: normal-distribution, variance, expected-value

If Z=X+Y and X and Y are independent and X~N($\mu_X$,$\sigma^2_X$) Y~N($\mu_Y$,$\sigma^2_Y$)

Can I say that E[Z] = E[X] + E[Y]

and Var[Z] = Var[X] + Var[Y]

I think this may be an insanely simple "yes" but I figured Id ask.

Comment: Let's start with the expectation. Can you rewrite it as an integral or sum?

Comment: @JohnMadden Im not told if it is discrete or continuous but the entire practice has been with discrete variables so I think I can write it as a sum. Edit So by the format of the sum, and since they are independent I can break up the X and Y into two different sums so I can split the expectation like that

Comment: Oh wait, are you just looking for a yes/no answer? I was going to lead you through a derivation. The answer is yes.

Comment: The first is called [linearity of expectation](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=linearity+expectation)  Although this is referenced thousands of times here on CV, I do not recall ever seeing a mathematical proof. It is a direct consequence of the distributive law of arithmetic.  The variance property is a special case of a the [blinearity property of variance](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?tab=votes&q=variance%20bilinear*) along with the fact that the covariance of independent (square integrable) variables is zero.

Comment: @JohnMadden Yeah I was just looking for a yes or no I thought it was yes but sometimes when things are simple I overthink and often screw myself over. Just looking at properties of sums by your comment helped me convince myself. I appreciate it.

Comment: @whuber Thanks for the knowledge!!

Comment: Since yes/no questions are not on topic here, I have closed this one.

Comment: @Andrew see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expected_value#Properties  and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variance#Basic_properties